# how to display files in shell script

Tags: shell

I have few files in BrowserStack and I want to display file name and then I want to delete that file with given custom_id. (BELOW IS SAMPLE OUTPUT)

```
[
  {
    "custom_id": "abcapp",
    "app_id": "abcapp"
   },
  {
    "custom_id": "xyzapp",
    "app_id": "xyzapp"
  },
  {
    "custom_id": "abcapp",
    "app_id": "abcapp"
  },
  {
    "custom_id": "xyzapp",
    "app_id": "xyzapp"
  },
  {
    "custom_id": "abcapp",
    "app_id": "abcapp"
  },
  {
    "custom_id": "abcapp",
    "app_id": "abcapp"
  }
]
```

I wrote shell script where I want to display & delete files

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in $(curl -u "xyz_u9sXFH:pqRfaqxRQpmxyJmzEqx" -X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq '.[] | select(.app_id=="abcapp")' | jq '.app_id')
do
   echo "Deleting $var"
   curl -u "xyz_u9sXFH:pqRfaqxRQpmxyJmzEqx" -X DELETE "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/app/delete/$var"
done
```

I am very new to shell script, so don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Note [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Beyond that, though -- please describe your script's _actual behavior_ as part of the question. (Also, make sure your sample data is complete enough to allow testing -- it doesn't include any `app_id` values at all, f/e, but your code won't work without one).

Comment: Also, note that `$var` should be _inside_ your double-quoted string on the `curl` line. Unquoted expansions are subject to a bunch of potentially-unwanted behaviors, depending on exactly what the values contain; it's easier to reason about code that never performs expansions unquoted.

Comment: Another hint you might use to better narrow down what's going wrong: Run `set -x` early in your script, or run it with `bash -x yourscript`, to enable trace-level logs.

Comment: BTW, why split the work into two separate `jq` invocations instead of having just one?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your input. So I was trying curl command at terminal and it's not giving any result. $(curl -u "xyz_u9sXFH:pqRfaqxRQpmxyJmzEqx" -X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq '.[] | select(.custom_id=="abcapp")' | jq -r '.app_id')

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/CaringThankfulMachinelanguage running your jq code against your data, and getting output that's in line with what's expected.

Comment: Might I suggest adding some `tee` operations into your pipeline? If you curl `curl ... | tee from-curl.json | jq ... | tee from-jq.json`, you'll be able to inspect `from-curl.json` and `from-jq.json` and make sure they look like what you expect. It'll also let you run a newer version of your jq code against the existing file on-disk so you can iterate on testing without hitting the actual web server over and over.